# How do I integrate jasmine into mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, mocha.js

I have a large set of unit test written in jasmine-node for a Node project. I want to use Mocha for the expanded feature set but I'm pretty in bed with jasmine both for style and extensive use of spies. I have several helpers and custom code that is very jasmine dependent.

How can I use jasmine-node or the jasmine library as the framework while mocha is the testing engine? Can the two play nicely or do I **have** to rewrite my testing environment for mocha, chai, and sinon?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use jasmine-node or the jasmine library as the framework while mocha is the testing engine?

What? Do you mean you want to code your tests against jasmine and then somehow run them in mocha? While I'm sure it's possible, it just sounds bizarre.

For a given suite of tests, it's one or the other. They have similar but different APIs so you have to choose one. Choosing BOTH in a single project is almost certainly poor judgement IMHO. Other than mocha's vastly superior async support, I can't see how you could justify using both when they are so closely related. It's just going to create a confusing annoyance for maintenance.

Suggestion: split your project apart into smaller, separate modules. Than you can port each of these smaller modules when the time is right if you want to migrate from jasmine to mocha.